# Problem with wifi Ubuntu 12.04, Qualcomm Atheros QCA95665

Tags: 12.04, wireless, atheros

I bought a Dell Inspiron 14 3442 laptop pre-installed with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS , however I am having issues with the WiFi connection. I receive the error message: `Has closed the connection` every time that I attempt to activate the network. Wired and bluetooth connections are working perfectly but issue is solely with wireless.

My wireless network card is a Qualcomm Atheros QCA95665 / AR9565.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:020c]
    Kernel modules: ath9k
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0651]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

And the output of `modinfo ath9k` are:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.5.0-60-generic/updates/dkms/ath9k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     BC752C884CE7A724FD00A1C
alias:          platform:qca955x_wmac
alias:          platform:ar934x_wmac
alias:          platform:ar933x_wmac
alias:          platform:ath9k
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000037sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000033sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000030sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000029sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000027sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000024sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000023sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        ath9k_hw,ath9k_common,mac80211,ath,compat,cfg80211
vermagic:       3.5.0-60-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           enable_diversity:Enable Antenna diversity for AR9565 (int)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the results of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` and `modinfo ath9k`